# this bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK 4.2

Tags: ios4, bundle

Dear Concerned,
My base sdk is 4.2 
deployment sdk is 3.1.2
I had done the following steps
  - Build the .app bundle for distribution for "Device" and "Distribution" in the drop down menu of the main XCode screen.
  - In the "Project Settings" the base SDK is 4.2 and your deployment target SDK to 3.1.2 both settings are found in that "Build" menu. 
  - Settings are made for the "ALL" configuration

But when i tried to upload the app through the application loader it fires the above error
Please guide me.... As I'm really stuck with it
Thanks & Regards,
Zahur

Answer (score 2):

Apple is currently not accepting applications made/compiled with the iOS 4.2 SDK, which is still a beta at this moment. You'll have to install the 4.1 SDK and compile your app against it and resubmit it.  You're base SDK will be 4.1 and deployment SDK 3.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't release applications built with BETA SDKs i'm afraid - grab 4.1 from developer.apple.com, rebuild and resubmit and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your deployment target to 3.1 or higher.  They are no longer accepting 3.0 applications as a ultra majority of the iPhone users have upgraded the iOS to 3.1.  I had the same problem.